# How do you make new editors open in another screen?

Tags: eclipse, multiple-monitors

I use dual monitor for work and I prefer to have the editor on my main screen while the rest of eclipse in my laptop monitor.

However, when I open a new file, that is. I open a file with Cmd-Shift-R, files are opened in my laptop monitor as opposed to the editor that I dragged to my main screen.

I find this mildly annoying. Any ideas?

[image: Picture shows a newly opened window on my laptop monitor which is the one on the right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are using the ***Window -> New Window*** feature?  In that case it depends on which window you're working on at the time you press **Ctrl+Shift+R**.

However, if you're streching only one Eclipse window along both monitors, then the *Open Resource* dialog will be opened in your "monitor number 1" (and that depends on your graphic configuration: Laptop+Main or Main+Laptop).

Comment: I opened the editor in the main window and other windows in the newly created window. Now Ctrl-3 will open correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found easier to avoid the new window menu and just to drag those views out of eclipse. This creates a secondary window but the project explorer is linked to the old window so double click will open the file on the main window.

I recommend to save everything as a new perspective that I usually call "Java 2 Windows". This way I can change perspectives when I do not have an auxiliar screen.

P.S. Just avoid closing the auxiliar window when leaving eclipse.